# Additional conditions for tasks inside a block

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm trying to enclose tasks in the block with some when condition. Also some tasks inside this block have additional conditions.
The problem is such tasks (with additional conditions) are skipped. Both block's condition and all additional conditions are true.

Below there is a sample play:

```
- block:    

    - set_fact: 
        packages_to_install: "{{ packages_to_install }} + [ '{{ (distrs.stdout | from_json).postgresql }}' ]"

    - set_fact:
        packages_to_install: "{{ packages_to_install }} + [ '{{ (distrs.stdout | from_json).webserver }}' ]"
  when:
    - server.webserver is defined
    - server.webserver == true   

  when:
    - server is defined
```

So, postgresql is added to the list of packages, but webserver is not.

According to [the docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_blocks.html), all tasks inside the block *will be executed after appending the when condition from the block and evaluating it in the task’s context*.
Maybe it's not just possible in Ansible 2.4 to have enclosed tasks with additional conditions?

Comment: Please fix the indentation issue – you have two `when:` clauses attached to `block:` statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should fix the indentation of the `when` declarations.

> Maybe it's not just possible in Ansible 2.4 to have enclosed tasks with additional conditions?

Ansible 2.4 works ok:

```
tasks:
  - block:

    - debug:
        msg: "task 1"

    - debug:
        msg: "task 2"
      when: false

    - debug:
        msg: "task 3"
      when: true

    when: true
```

results in:

```
TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "task 1"
}

TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "task 3"
}
```

---

And you can always reorder the keys in `block` task for clarity:

```
tasks:
  - when: true
    block:
      - debug:
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip related to keys reorganization - this way it's much cleaner:)

Comment: As to my original problem - actually there was an error in one of my conditions. The 'server.webserver' holds JSON data, and there was no boolean flag. So I fixed the condition and everything started working as expected. Indentations were OK - I just inaccurately posted the code here.